# formal way of asking help & information

Tags: phrase-requests, formality

i want to write an email to professor to get an information about result of shortlisted candidates in university. what is formal way to ask him to "let me know".

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can end your mail with the statement- Looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: are there any statements other this?